# How to restart/reinitialize a Backbone Marionette Module

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I have a Backbone Marionette application that is structured using Modules. I have a situation where I want to reinitialize a module but when I try to do this nothing happens. Here's the situation:-

The first time the module is used the initialization handlers fire as they should. The module can then be stopped at some point in the future when the user goes elsewhere in the app. I want the module to then be reused if necessary and I want the initializers to fire at this point. I assumed that firing the module's start command would run through the initialization handlers again but when I do it, nothing happens.

Any ideas how I can restart a Marionette module in this way? I was trying to avoid setting up some kind of custom init command that would need firing manually.....

Thanks,

Sam

Answer (score 2):

You need to stop the module first. Call `.stop()` and the module's finalizers will be run, putting the module in to a state where it can be started again. Once you have called `stop()`, you will be able to call `.start()` again.

Comment: Hi Derick, thanks so much for getting back to me. And more importantly thanks so, so much for all the amazing work, effort and time you have put into Marionette. It is awesome! The Modules I am trying to restart have already had stop called on them BUT they are initially loaded into the application as Require modules. Sorry for not including this in the original post. Do you think it would effect the behaviour as I am describing above?

Comment: This is really valuable! I have a submodule that sometimes gets loaded before the parent module, so when the parent gets loaded I must stop it and re-start it with the custom initializers. Thanks!